# Get Name of Object in Array in Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js

```
var MD5 = require("crypto-js/md5");
var hash = [MD5, SHA1, SHA256, SHA224, SHA512, SHA384, SHA3, RIPEMD160];

console.log(JSON.stringify(hash[1]));
```

outputs undefined. I want it to output MD5 how can I do this?

```
console.log(hash[1].constructor.name);
```

outputs "Function"

Comment: Why do you expect `hash[1]` to be related to `MD5`? Clearly it should be something related to `SHA1` (which indeed in your sample is undefined).

Answer (score -1):

You shouldn't have to find the name property under the constructor. Try doing:

```
console.log(hash[0].name);
```

and it should print out MD5 if the code you are requiring under `require("crypto-js/md5");` is a function.

Also note the edit to change `hash[1]` to `hash[0]`. JS arrays start at index 0.

Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/name

Comment: this should work but console.log(MD5.name); doesn't output anything

Comment: An alternative would be to manually set the name yourself. `var MD5 = require("crypto-js/md5"); MD5.name = "MD5";` It's a few extra lines of code but it'll do the job.

Comment: yikes, this outputs nothing: 
var MD5 = require("crypto-js/md5");
MD5.name = "MD5";
console.log(MD5.name);

Comment: I just tested it out too. It seems to only be erasing the .name property, i've tried .fnName and .fname and those stick on. I'll research a bit on what's going on.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/name Yea I guess .name is a `readonly` property.

Answer (score -1):

If it outputs function, that means it's an anonymous function.

For instance, both func0 and func1 are functions.

```
var func0 = function (){}
var func1 = function func(){}

console.log(func0.name); // nothing...
console.log(func1.name); // func
```

When you try this, you should see empty for name.

```
var MD5 = require("crypto-js/md5");
console.log('MD5.name:' ,MD5.name); // 'MD5.name'
```

Comment: so how do I get the name?